# Formula for range based attenuation

Tags: opengl, c++, rendering, glsl

I am trying to implement a simple shader for point lights, but I am struggling with the attenuation function. I know that normally you would use three coefficients (constant, linear, and quadratic), however in my framework point lights only have position, intensity (color) and range.

Is there any formula that only requires the light's range to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three-coefficient attenuation is just a crutch used for tuning lights in the fixed pipeline; you definitely shouldn't worry about it when implementing a shader.

In physics light attenuates according to the [inverse-square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law), for which only distance is required.  In computer graphics *sometimes* a simpler linear attenuation is preferable.  Again, only distance is required.